# how to inject div in an html?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html string as follow:

```
<div data-field-id="ListFieldId1" data-field-type="ListField">
            <div id="1">
                <div>
                    some text
            </div>
            <img src="source" />
            <div>
                some text
            </div>
            <div>
                some text
            </div>
            <a href="link">click</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in my web page I have a button that when pressed the `div` part by `id="1"` should be injected to the main `div` with `id="2"` using jquery. I tried in this way that i have variable `listHtml` equals `<div id="1">...</div>` and `listCount` as default id. I tried to set a new id for listHtml in this way:

```
listHtml.attr('id', (listCount + 1).toString());
```

but this line doesn't work!

in fact after this work I want to `append(listHtml)`.

how can I fix it?

Is there any other way to inject a div tag to html?

thanks.

Comment: Instead of describing your jQuery, could you *show* us your jQuery?

Comment: @DavidThomas : type.append(self.listHtml); //type is main div

Comment: @DeeMac: no.and i want to produce it

Comment: Which div is the main div? It's a bit unclear at the moment what you want to do.

Comment: @DeeMac: I mean this as main div: <div data-field-id="ListFieldId1" data-field-type="ListField">...</div>

Comment: What's the button? The `a` you mean?

Comment: @DeeMac: no. the button is an other element of the page that gonna inject the <div id="2">...</div> to the main div as I said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following code lines may help you, if I understand your problem correctly.

**Note:** I have included "id" on divs etc for brevity and for quick readability.

```
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add Div" />
<div id="divMain" data-field-id="ListFieldId1" data-field-type="ListField">
    <div id="1">
        <div>
            some text
        </div>
        <img src="source" />
        <div>
            some text
        </div>
        <div>
            some text
        </div>
        <a href="link">click</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
        var div = $("#divMain").children('div').last();
        var nextDivId = div.attr("id");

        var newDiv = div.clone();
        newDiv.attr("id", Number(nextDivId) + 1);
        $("#divMain").append(newDiv);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That should do the job
`$.('#1').append($('<div id="'+(listid+1)+'">...</div>'));`

Comment: but we don't have id="2"

Comment: If you want to dynamically create a div make jQuery object out of it before appending

Answer (score 1):

You have to create Jquery Object before you want to make change in any attribute of that element. Otherwise it treated it as simple string not an element.

**For Example**

```
var listHtml = '<div id="1">New Div</div> ';
var ele = $(listHtml);
ele.attr('id', (listCount + 1).toString()); //here you can make change in id attribute.
```

May this will help you.

Here is  [**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/na7ah9ce/1/) to add dynamic div.

Answer (score 1):

```
function addNewDiv()
{
    $("#yourDiv").append('<div id="'+ listCount++ +'">Div "' + listCount  +'" </div>');   
}
```

Hope this helps